# TableView Laggy Issue | iOS-Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I've created a plain `TableView` but when i scroll the tableview for certain amount of time like 5 mins on same screen, then after that it starts been looking very laggy scroll.

Here is my code snippet -

**TableView Delegates:-**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newFriendCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Text cell";
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 400;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 200;
}
```

> NOTE - I need to integrate multi type cell in tableView

Comment: A couple of minor improvements would be: use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` so you don't have to test for a nil cell, and store the result of `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]` in an instance variable so you don't repeat cache lookups.  Other than that, I suggest using Instruments to investigate what's happening during the slowdown.

Comment: @PhillipMills - Ok let me check.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to set background color on *contentView* of a cell, not on cell itself. Another thing you can do is to setup a cell in **tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:** and leave in **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** just initialization.

Comment: Ok let me check.